# Display PDF from VarBinary in ASP.NET View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf, view

I am trying to display a pdf embedded on the page.  I have been successful in being able to store the pfd in a varbinary field in the database on the sql server.

The `byte[]` array returns the binary value for the pdf correctly as well, the issue is that it does not get converted to pdf on the view.

Step1 :
Here is my model:

```
public class Writing
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public byte[] Material { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePublished { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my controller which is performing the successful insert operation:

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Insert(Writing writing,List<IFormFile> Material)
    {
        foreach(var item in Material)
        {
            if (item.Length > 0)
            {
                using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await item.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    writing.Material = stream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        dbContext.Writings.Add(writing);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("AdminIndex");
    }
```

Here is the view where result is being displayed as binary and not pdf:

```
   @{
   var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Material);
   var book = string.Format("data:application/pdf;base64,{0}", base64);
   }
  <article>
      <h1> @Model.Title</h1>
      <h5>@Model.Author</h5> <h5>@Model.DatePublished</h5>
      <object data=@book type="application/pdf" width="300px" height="900px">
    <p><b>Example fallback content</b>: This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf">Download PDF</a>.</p>
     </object>
 </article>
```

I am expecting to see a pdf but the page is empty and after bringing up the Console Window(f12).  I can see the binary value of the pdf being returned. The other values of the Model display correctly on the page.

Step 2 :
I have even tried the following :

```
   [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Read(int ID)
    {
        var article = Find(ID);
        return File(article.Material, "application/pdf");
    }
```

This does return the pdf but with binary value on top of the pdf. And the pdf, opens in the same tab which is quite inconvenient.

Update: I just figured Step2 out, it was as simple as adding `target=_blank` to the link tag.

Does anybody have suggestions to make either Step 1 work  ?

Comment: you need to save the PDF somewhere then give alinik to the saved version

Comment: can you elaborate